# Why do salts form ions?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons

For example, sodium chloride is formed because a chlorine atom  "takes" one electron from a sodium atom, thus forming a sodium+ and a chlorine- ion which stick together because of their different charge. But how can this separated charge state be of lower energy than each atom being uncharged?

I do not understand why this charge transfer hppens, since each uncharged atom "looks" electrically neutral because the electrons surround the nucleus.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Thin kin terms of free energy change the change in entropy is negative and the change in enthalpy is also negative so change in free energy would be negative this implies that the process is spontaneous